# What assumptions can be made about the CFArrayCallBacks used to create a CFArray?

Tags: objective-c, macos-carbon

I am writing an [`SCDynamicStoreCallBack`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Networking/Reference/SCDynamicStore/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/SCDynamicStoreCallBack), which has the signature:

```
typedef void (*SCDynamicStoreCallBack)    (
   SCDynamicStoreRef    store,
   CFArrayRef           changedKeys,
   void                *info
   );
```

I am considering using CFArrayContainsValue() to check whether `changedKeys` contains a particular key.

The documentation for CFArrayContainsValue() says that the behavior depends on the equal callback specified when the array was created.  In this case, the `changedKeys` array is provided to me by the system and I do not know what equal callback is used to create this array.

Is it documented anywhere that I can assume that system-created arrays are created with `kCFTypeArrayCallBacks`?